# Access for specific page

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

Is it possible to give only certain groups access to a **single page** in Sharepoint Online?

I can only find access settings for the whole communication site or for folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the library that stores the page, click **Manage access**> **Advanced**>**Stop inheriting permissions** and set unique permission(certain groups access) for this single page:

[image]